# Laravel controller with multiple beforeFilter's

Tags: laravel, filter

I need to filter different authorization roles for different HTTP verbs. Attaching one filter in the controller is no problem, as the example shows:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->beforeFilter('roleOne', ['on' => ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']]);
}
```

However, attaching multiple filters, as the next example shows, hides all the routes from the caller.

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->beforeFilter('roleOne', ['on' => ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']]);
  $this->beforeFilter('roleTwo', ['on' => ['get']]);
}
```

And combining the filters lets all traffic through.

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->beforeFilter('roleOne|roleTwo', ['on' => ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']]);
}
```

Both fails.

I've considered using user levels instead of role names, or attaching level values to the user roles. But the best scenario for me would be to avoid having to change the structure.

**Edit**, here's the general structure for my filters.

```
Route::filter('roleOne', function ($route, $request){

  $token = $request->header('X-Auth-Token');

  // If the token doesn't exist the user isn't authenticated
  if ($token === null) {
    $data = ['Not authenticated'];
    $code = 401;

    $response = Response::json([
      'error' => true,
      'data' => $data,
      'code' => $code
      ], $code
    );

    return $response;
  }

  // If the token is invalid the user isn't authenticated
  else if ( ! isAuthenticated($token) ) {
    $data = ['Not authenticated'];
    $code = 401;

    $response = Response::json([
      'error' => true,
      'data' => $data,
      'code' => $code
      ], $code
    );

    return $response;
  }

  // If the user is not a member of group s/he doesn't have access
  if( ! isAuthorized($token, 'roleOne') ){
    $data = ['Not authorized'];
    $code = 401;

    $response = Response::json([
      'error' => true,
      'data' => $data,
      'code' => $code
      ], $code
    );

    return $response;
  }

});
```

Comment: How about `roleOne|roleTwo` for `get` and `roleOne` for the others?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I'm pretty sure it's because one filter returns an error before the others are tested. But how do I make sure to test all filters before returning an error?

Comment: Well that's supposed to happen. Filters can be combined only with an "and operator" all filters have to pass.

Comment: I see - that is what I assumed. I'll work out a solution with levels then, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yes do that :) [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28293813/1903366) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up introducing a level parameter in the authorized groups. Then I only needed one single beforeFilter.

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->beforeFilter('userRole', ['on' => ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']]);
}
```

And the filter now lookes something like...

```
Route::filter('userRole', function ($route, $request){

  $token = $request->header('X-Auth-Token');

  // If the token doesn't exist the user isn't authenticated
  if ($token === null) {
    $data = ['Not authenticated'];
    $code = 401;

    $response = Response::json([
      'error' => true,
      'data' => $data,
      'code' => $code
      ], $code
    );

    return $response;
  }

  // If the token is invalid the user isn't authenticated
  else if ( ! isAuthenticated($token) ) {
    $data = ['Not authenticated'];
    $code = 401;

    $response = Response::json([
      'error' => true,
      'data' => $data,
      'code' => $code
      ], $code
    );

    return $response;
  }

  // If the user is not a member of group Admin s/he doesn't have access
  if( ! isAuthorized($token, 'Admin') ){
    $data = ['Not authorized'];
    $code = 401;

    $response = Response::json([
      'error' => true,
      'data' => $data,
      'code' => $code
      ], $code
    );

    return $response;
  }

});
```

And the isAuthorized method looks something like this.

```
public function isAuthorized($token, $group) {
  $hasPermission = false;

  $user = false;
  $requiredGroup = false;

  // Attempting to find the user will automatically throw errors if unsuccessful
  try {
    if( $group !== '*' ){
      // Get the needed group
      $requiredGroup = $this->groupProvider->findByName($group);        
    }

    // Get the user, including the memberships
    $user = $this->userProvider->findByToken($token);
  } catch (InvalidTokenException $e) {
    $hasPermission = false;
  }

  // If the group is '*' it means everyone has permission, but has to be authenticated!
  // That's why we do this check after the token-check
  if ( $group === '*' ) {
    return true;
  }

  if( !$user || !$requiredGroup ) {
    $hasPermission = false;
  } else {
    // Compare user permissions to required
    foreach ($user['groups'] as $group) {
      if( $group['level'] >= $requiredGroup['level'] ){
        $hasPermission = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return $hasPermission;
}
```